# Python - PHPSESSID

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Bom estou tentando criar um *script* que entre em um site sem precisar fazer login através da biblioteca `requests`. Quero fazer usando o cookie do `PHPSESSID`.

Como posso fazer isto?

Comment: Porquê sem a biblioteca requests?

Comment: na vdd eu preciso dela, o problema e que nao quero enviar login/senha. somente quero enviar o PHPSESSID ao inves de ter que logar entende?É q o site que eu quero entrar tem captcha ai nao tem como enviar os formularios, entao o jeito seria logar atraves do browser, pegar os cookies e fazer meio q um 'hijack'.

Comment: Percebo, mas como quer agarrar o PHPSESSID válido sem fazer login antes? Isso vai ter de ser verificado do lado servidor e o servidor vai ver se PHPSESSID equivale ao que ele tem guardado para essa sessão. E isso só definido quando se faz o login... Sem login PHPSESSID neste contexto não existe. Pode fazer tudo isso com requests... Se puder dizer, qual é o site? a ver se o consigo ajudar

Comment: claro, mas eu farei o login atraves do browser, ai eu pego o ID do browser e jogo no meu script.

Comment: Ha ok... Percebo. Vai ter de enviar todos os cookies... Muito provávelmente não vai ter só esse guardado

Comment: o site e br.hackerexperience.com

Comment: br.hackerexperience.com

Comment: Você sabe qual o código necessário pra enviar cookie através do requests?

Comment: Coloquei em baixo, a maneira de fazer isso, juntamente com o link da documentação

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para enviar os cookies juntamente com o *request*, usando a lib [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/):

```
import requests

s = requests.Session()

r = s.get('http://httpbin.org/cookies', cookies={'CHAVE1': 'VALOR1', 'CHAVE2': 'VALOR2'})
print(r.status_code)
print(r.text)
```

Lembre-se que provavelmente não existe só um cookie de verificação, terá de enviar todos. Este exemplo em princípio funciona tanto em python2 como em 3.

Pode definir os headers também e enviar juntamente:

```
...
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0'}
r = s.get('http://httpbin.org/cookies', headers=headers, cookies={'CHAVE1': 'VALOR1', 'CHAVE2': 'VALOR2'})
```

Comment: ok obrigado! vou testar

Comment: Muito obrigado consegui enviando somente o PHPSESSID muito obrigado mesmo estava pesquisando há dois dias.

Comment: pronto amigo cliquei !